# Is there a way to programmatically retrieve a dependency in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, baseline

The use case is baselineing an osgi bundle.

I would like to retrieve from configured repositories the specified release (or the latest release) of a specified artifact (the one currently just built) such that I can use the jar file in a baseline operation (which requires the previous version and the new version).

Is there any gradle API that can be used for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can access a project's dependencies like this:

`configurations.compile.allDependencies` from there you can iterate the `DependencySet` and do what you need to do.

**Note**: You may need to do this in an `afterEvaluate` closure because dependencies are not configured until after. So something like this:

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    def dependencySet = configurations.compile.allDependencies
    def dependenciesSize = dependencySet.size()
    for (int i = 0; i < dependenciesSize; i++) {
        def dependency = dependencySet.getAt(i)
        if (dependency.group != null && dependency.name != null) {
            if (dependency.group.equals("com.project.group") &&
                    dependency.name.equals("my-project")) {
                // Do what you need to do with the dependency you found.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working as for gradle v 3.1.4 (dependecies size is always 0)